# Tangets relation to local shape of surface.

Tags: differential-geometry

I am having a hard time to reconcile with the fact that the first fundamental form determine the local shape of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in the sense that the angles between the tangets out of a point determenies its shape.

How does one think of this in a way in which this is apparent.

Comment: The first fundamental form does **not** determine the local shape -- the first fundamental form at each point of a cylinder is the same as the form for each point of the plane, or a corrugated sheet, or even a punctured cone. I think perhaps you were misled somewhat. Of course, one might regard all of these as having the same "local shape" in terms of intrinsic geometry, but that amounts to saying that the first FF determines...everything that the first FF determines.

Comment: @John Hughes it determines the gaussian curvature, isnt that shape?

Comment: That's ONE kind of shape. If you think a cylinder and a plane and a corrugated piece of sheet metal all have the same "shape", then you're right and the "intuition" is gauss's theorem egregium -- more intuitive to some folks than to others.